# Livewire sum input array and display on page

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, properties, laravel-livewire

I have a simple form with an array input of `hours`. As user types in the hours into each (or some) of the `hours` inputs i'd like to sum those and show in a div on the page. What happens, however, is that the `$this->hours_count` array gets [reset / reinitialized](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1702) every time another hour array input is typed.

The `$this->hours_count` always shows up correctly when I Save / Create the item in form->store but not during the input process.

This seems as simple as the livewire [quickstart counter example](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart#add-counter) but I cannot wrap my head around it. I understand properties and variables get re-initialized in Livewire but the docs state that [public properties](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#important-notes) do not. Any help in the right direction is much apricated. - Patryk

Livewire Component:

```
public $hours = [];
public $hours_count = [];

protected function rules()
    {
        return [    
            'hours.*.amount' => 'nullable|numeric|min:.25|max:16',
        ];
    }
public function updatedHours($field)
    {
         //get $this->hours key/index
         $hours_index = substr($field,6, -7);
         $this->hours_count[$hours_index] = $this->hours[$hours_index]['amount'];
    }
```

Blade File:

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="Store">
    <x-forms.row 
        wire:model"hours.{{$index}}.amount">
   </x-forms.row>
</form

..some <div> to display sum of $this->hours_count
```

Comment: You're certain it gets populated in your `updated` function? Something like a `dd` gave you the expected result? And then on render it's back to an empty `array`?

Comment: It did not. I was incorrect to dd inside livewire methods that are within the life cycle. Also, I was incorrect in trying to calculate a value as a component public property. The correct answer was to use a computed property as suggested by a user on the #livewire discord. I will updated this answer with references as soon as possible when I'm at a desktop.